# What is the structure that SQL Server uses to build and maintain indexes called?

Tags: sql-server, index

What is the structure that SQL Server uses to build and maintain indexes called?

Answer (score 7):

They are generally B+ Trees for your standard clustered and non-clustered indexes:

[B+ Tree Indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree)

Columnstore indexes have a different structure:

[Columnstore Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx)

In SQL server 2014 you have some new types too for the in-memory tables such as the Bw-Tree index:

[Bw-Tree Indexes](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=178758)

And the hash index:

[Guidelines for Using Indexes on Memory-Optimized Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133166%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Not forgetting the full text indexes too:

[Full Text Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142505%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

As pointed out there are also spatial indexes:

[Spatial Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

And XML Indexes:

[XML indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191497.aspx)